# How to create a simple non CRUD screen in Jhipster?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have started working with `Jhipster` and angular 9 for the very first time and I am at beginner level.
I have created entities using `jhipster` generation, which are nothing but `CRUD` screens. I also want to create some screens that are simple Forms with submit button below, without any `Search/Edit/View/Delete` functionality. Is that possible from `Jhipster`?

Comment: JHipster won't help you to generate these screens, you must code them manually.

Comment: As far as I know, in the list of the entity generated, if you click the Edit/Delete,  then the screen will change to simple Form with submit button. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes Alvin, is there any way in jhipster to directly create these screens rather than entire CRUD?